# Share Screenshot of Game through Facebook Unity SDK without URL

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to share a screenshot of my game directly to the user's feed. While this seems to be possible through the iOS Facebook SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios like so,

```
   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
  photo.image = image;
  photo.userGenerated = YES;
  FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
  content.photos = @[photo];
  ...
}
```

I cannot find the corresponding functionality in the Unity version of the SDK.Searches on the web tell me to upload the photos to the user's albums using FB.API and then use FB.FeedShare using the created link which seems an incorrect approach.